# Set custom varaible name in for loop Vue js

Tags: for-loop, vue.js, input, vue-component

Below is my code.This is not working because i want to make a dynamic key of object.

```
<li v-for="index in 6" :key="index"> 
    <div class="input-fld">
        <div class="field">
            <p class="control has-icons-right">
                <input type="text" v-model="formData[0].'line_'{{index}}'_text'"/> 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>         
</li>
```

I want like this

```
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="formData[0].line_1_text"/>
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="formData[0].line_2_text"/>
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="formData[0].line_3_text"/>
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="formData[0].line_4_text"/>
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="formData[0].line_5_text"/>
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="formData[0].line_6_text"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set custom names by bracket notation:

```
<li v-for="index in 6" :key="index"> 
<div class="input-fld">
    <div class="field">
        <p class="control has-icons-right">
            <input type="text" v-model="formData[0]['line_' + index + '_text']"/> 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```